# Best way combining 4 lists into one

Tags: java, list, tree, hashmap

I have to preprocess 4 lists of medical data before we can import it into the software.
I have given 4 lists, each ordered already, that look like the following:

```
File 1) chapter
A00-B99;
C00-D48;
D50-D89;
C00-C99;
E00-E90;
...
Z00-Z99;

File 2) subchapter
A00-A09;
A15-A19;
A92-A99;
B95-B98;
B99-B99;
C00-C48;
...
Z80-Z99;

File 3) Groups
A00.-
A01.-
A02.-
...
C01.-
....
Z99.-

File 4) diagnoses

A00.0;
A00.1;
A00.7;
A00.8;
A01.7;
A02.8;
..
Z00.3;
Z00.4;
```

;

At the End it shoud be ordered as the list below.
Each line will be a line within a csv-file.

```
A00-B99; (Chapter)
A00-A09; (Subchapter)
A00.-    (corresponding group)
A00.0    (corresponding diagnoses)
A00.1
A00.7
A00.8
A01.-    (corresponding group)
A01.7    (corresponding diagnoses)
A02.-    (corresponding group)
A02.8    (corresponding diagnoses)
...
B15-B99(Subchapter)
...
C00-C99 (Chapter)
C00-D48 (Subchapter)
C01.-   (corresponding group)
C01.2   (corresponding diagnoses)
```

I've tried it so far by using some linked hasmaps but don't get the correct result.

```
while (entries_kapitel.hasNext()) {

    Entry thisEntry_kapitel = (Entry) entries_kapitel.next();
    String key_kapitel = (String) thisEntry_kapitel.getKey();
    String text_kapitel = (String) thisEntry_kapitel.getValue();

    // A00-B99 -> A und B
    String kapitel_char1 = key_kapitel.split("-")[0].substring(0, 1);
    String kapitel_char2 = key_kapitel.split("-")[1].substring(0, 1);

    // A00-B99 -> 99
    int kapitel_int2 = Integer.parseInt(key_kapitel.split("-")[1].substring(1, 3));
     // subchapters
     while (entries_gruppen.hasNext()) {

            Entry thisEntry_gruppen = (Entry) entries_gruppen.next();
            String key_gruppen = (String) thisEntry_gruppen.getKey();
            String text_gruppen = (String) thisEntry_gruppen.getValue();

            // Gruppe splitten T90-T89
            String gruppe_char1 = key_gruppen.split("-")[0].substring(0, 1);
            String gruppe_char2 = key_gruppen.split("-")[1].substring(0, 1);
            int gruppe_int2 = Integer.parseInt(key_gruppen.split("-")[1].substring(1, 3));


            if (gruppe_char1.equals(gruppe_char2) == false){
                System.err.println("Subchapters start with the same capital!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
             while (entries_gruppierung.hasNext()) {
             Entry thisEntry_gruppierung = (Entry) entries_gruppierung.next();
                String key_gruppierung = (String) thisEntry_gruppierung.getKey();
                String text_gruppierung = (String) thisEntry_gruppierung.getValue();

                String gruppierung_char1 = key_gruppierung.substring(0, 1);
                int gruppierung_int1 =        Integer.parseInt(key_gruppierung.substring(1, 3));
 (gruppierung_char1.equals(gruppe_char1) && gruppierung_int1 <= gruppe_int2) {
                    System.out.println("Chapter: " + key_kapitel + "     subchapter: " + key_gruppen + " group" + key_gruppierung);


                 while (diagnoses.hasNext()) {
                 ....
```

The result does not look like it should (there are missing entries and they are not all ordered correctly)
What is the best way to solve this task? 
I was not able to get a working tree, which probably is the best way to go, right?

Comment: I personally would load the file into a database e.g embed derby, then perform some sort of sql select statement in JDBC

Comment: I would recomment first putting the data you recieve in a structure which actually fits what you are trying to modell: Create a Chapter Class which contains a List of Subchapter Objects, which in turn contain a list of Group objects etc. pp. Working with a structure like this would probably be much easier then trying to fiddle with a bunch of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

If I understod well you're needs. I would use a SORT / MERGE join approach. Consider 4 lists containing the entries, properly sorted. Then you can merge the lists by scanning them alternately. I haven't tested the code but you'll get the general idea :

```
public class EntryComparator implements Comparator<Entry>
{
    public boolean isSubsection(Entry e1, Entry e2)
    {
       // should return true if e2 subsection of e1
    }

    public int compare(Entry e1, Entry e2)
    {
       // see the Comparator interface documentation
    }
}

List<Entry> chapters = new ArrayList<>();
List<Entry> subchapters = new ArrayList<>();
List<Entry> groups = new ArrayList<>();
List<Entry> diagnoses = new ArrayList<>();

List<Entry> result = new ArrayList<>(); // will hold the final result

// populate the lists, maybe sort them using Collections.sort and the Comparator above

int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
int i3 = 0;
int i4 = 0;

EntryComparator c = new EntryComparator();

while( i1 < chapters.size() )
{
    result.add(chapters.get(i1));
    while( i2 < subchapters.size() && 
           c.isSubsection(chapters.get(i1), subchapters.get(i2)) )
    {
        result.add(subchapters.get(i2));
        while( i3 < groups.size() && 
               c.isSubsection(subchapters.get(i2), groups.get(i3)) )
        {
            result.add(groups.get(i3));
            while( i4 < subchapters.size() && 
                   c.isSubsection(groups.get(i3), diagnoses.get(i4)) )
            {
                result.add(diagnoses.get(i4));
                i4++;
            }
            i3++;
        }
        i2++;
    }
    i1++;
}
```

EDIT : the advice given by 911DidBush is a good one, you may apply the same pattern with specialized classes.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies. As recommended, I will implement each list as a Class. This seems a really good idea. The Class Chapter will look like this. The other classes are having the same structure as well.

```
public class Chapter {

private String key_chapter;
private String text;

private ArrayList<Subchapter> subchapters = new ArrayList<>();

public Chapter(String chapter, String text) {
    this.key_chapter = chapter;
    this.text = text;
    subchapters = new ArrayList<Subchapter>();
}

public String getChapter() {
    return key_chapter;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void addSubchapter(String subchapter, String text) {
    subchapters.add(new Subchapter(subchapter, text));
}

public Subchapter getKeyAtIndex(int index) {
    return subchapters.get(index);
}

// get the entire ArrayList:
public ArrayList getListOfSubchapters() {
    return subchapters;

}
}
```